# How can I take the like pages from an user of Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a problem. I am using fql to get user information. I want to take the pages the user has liked.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql

I have been investigating all tables, but I have not seen what I wanted.

If you know how can I do it, that would be fantastic.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the page_fan table

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan

uid should be an indexable field
here's a sample FQL query to get you started

```
select page_id,name from page where page_id in (select page_id from page_fan where uid=me())
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20page_id%2Cname%20from%20page%20where%20page_id%20in%20(select%20page_id%20from%20page_fan%20where%20uid%3Dme())